# jqgrid with datepicker not show?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2, datepicker

implement datepicker with jqgrid and now not list when add editoptions.

[HERE MY CODE JSP](http://pastebin.com/awQwq8s9)

//JAVASCRIPT

```
function DatePick (elem) {
  alert("HELLOW 1");
  jQuery(elem).datepicker(
      // {} // options here
     $(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy.mm.dd'})
  );
 }
function DateVal(){ 
var currentTime = new Date(); 
var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1); 
month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month; 
var day = currentTime.getDate(); 
day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day; 
var year = currentTime.getFullYear(); 
return year+"-"+month + "-"+day; 
}
```

//JQGRID

```
    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID"/><sjg:gridColumn name="nombre"
     index="nombre" title="Name" sortable="true"   search="true" editable="true"/> 
    <sjg:gridColumn name="fecha" index="fecha" title="Fecha" editable="true" 
      formatter="date" edittype="text" editoptions="{dataInit:function(el){ 
        $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});},defaultValue:DateVal}"/>
     </sjg:grid>
```

///////UPDATE
THANKS TO MY <3 THE SOLUTION ONLY IS IN "loadAtOnce".

Comment: Post the **relevant** code here, and explain clearly what the problem is and what you've attempted to solve it.

Comment: Also, didn't you [already ask this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598269/implement-date-picker-to-struts2-jqgrid)??

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem has to do with some css?